# USAirports Mobile XPages Example

Tags: mobile, project, xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

I am trying to make a mobile application with xpages on lotus domino designer 8.5.3.
I found a tutorial that perfectly explains the approach to develop mobile applications with xpages. The problem is that the example cited is not found on the net: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzeumkm2vbvz701/ADMIN_DEV_USAirports.nsf

I would like to know if I could find a functional link or if anyone can re-share this project.

Thanks

Comment: The presentation using the US Airports app as example was given by Bruce Elgort. Try asking him: http://bruceelgort.com/2012/05/24/my-slide-decks-from-admindev2012/

Comment: I saw the presentation at AdminDev2012 and it really is that easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the file you are looking for:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8eta7nc3a4f95l/ADMIN_DEV_USAirports.nsf

Thank you for letting me know it was missing.

Bruce

Comment: Thanks Bruce for the immediate assistance.Good continuation